# piccasso square not rendering images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-image

In the below code, when i use the images urls in my url variable and pass them to an adapter class which i created, piccasso renders those images into the gridview perfectly well. the getCurrentDetails() methode downloads the urls from online using JsonObject and jsonArray. the returned image urls are stored in the global variable mSmallImagesUrl. But when i pass the mSmallIMagesUrl as a parameter of my adapter, piccasso doesn't render the images, they are blank. but when i use the hardcoded image urls in the url variable, it works. Also the mSmallImagesUrl print the right image urls into log cat.So i am sure its not a pb when reading the images urls from online. please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks. bellow is the code

```
package com.paveynganpi.allsearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ImageGrid extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = ImageGrid.class.getSimpleName();
protected String mEditedString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_grid);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mEditedString = intent.getStringExtra("space"); //contains the edited string



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_image_grid, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    protected GridView mGridView;//reference to gridview in fragment_image_grid.xml
    protected int start = 4;//variable to change pages from google Api

    //contains extra images urls to supply to ... when need
    protected ArrayList<String> mBigImagesUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    //contains image urls to inject into gridview
    protected ArrayList<String> mSmalImagesUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_grid, container, false);



        String[] url = {
                "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02788/eden-hazard_2788463b.jpg",
                "http://statsbomb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Eden-Hazard-1.jpg",
                "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02788/eden-hazard_2788463b.jpg",
                "http://statsbomb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Eden-Hazard-1.jpg",
                "http://i3.getwestlondon.co.uk/incoming/article6086661.ece/alternates/s2197/Eden-Hazard.jpg",
                "http://fullfifa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/arton10532.jpg",
                "http://d.ibtimes.co.uk/en/full/1384908/eden-hazard.jpg",
                "http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/16s118hazard1tSX-459966.jpg",
        };

        final ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        String value= args.getString("space");

        String imagesUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="
                + value +"&rsz=8&start=" + start;


        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

            //using okHttp library to connect to imagesUrl and retrieve JSON Data
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(imagesUrl).
                            build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);

            //runs the below code asynchronously
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "error from request");

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        } else {
                            mSmalImagesUrls = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                            for(int i =0;i<mSmalImagesUrls.size(); i++){

                                //Log.d(TAG,mSmalImagesUrls.get(i));

                                //testList.add(mSmalImagesUrls.get(i));
                                testList.add(mSmalImagesUrls.get(i));
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught :", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        for(int i =0; i< url.length;i++){
            //testList.add(mBigImagesUrls.get(i).trim());
            testList.add(url[i]);

        }


        mGridView =(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesGrid);//reference to gridview
        ImagesGridAdapter adapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(getActivity(),mSmalImagesUrls);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);



        return rootView;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONObject responseData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");

        ArrayList<String> localList = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray results = responseData.getJSONArray("results");

        for(int i =0;i<results.length(); i++){

            localList.add(results.getJSONObject(i).getString("url"));

        }

        return localList;

    }

    //An AlertDialog to display to user when an error occurs
    private void alertUserAboutError() {

        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"error_dialog");


    }

    //checks if user is connected to a network
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;

        if(activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;


    }

}
```

}

below is my adapter class

```
package com.paveynganpi.allsearch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
```

/**
 * Created by paveynganpi on 1/22/15.
 */
public class ImagesGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
protected static final String TAG = ImagesGridAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
protected Context mContext;
protected ArrayList<String> mPicUrls;

public ImagesGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> picUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.images_view_grid_layout,picUrls);
    mContext = context;
    mPicUrls = picUrls;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.images_view_grid_layout,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.photoImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.googleImageView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);//makes us return to initial state of listview after viewing the content

    }
    else{
        holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();//gets the view holder that was already created
        //if tag is no set as above, error will result due to the fact we are trying to retrieve a tag
        //that is no longer available


    }

    //holder.authorImageView.setI(mTitle_authors.get(position).getAuthor());
    Picasso.with(mContext).
            load(mPicUrls.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .resize(300, 300)
            .into(holder.photoImageView);
    //Log.d(TAG,"title is ....." + mTitle_authors.get(0).getTitle());


    return convertView;
}


public static class ViewHolder{

    ImageView photoImageView;

}
```

}

the json response i received is below

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"620","height":"387","imageId":"ANd9GcTFohFJ8qoz1khvOSGcs2ECNfM_07JslDbVwEFP9t2GCAaZa8pNc6DwE_Y","tbWidth":"136","tbHeight":"85","unescapedUrl":"http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02788/eden-hazard_2788463b.jpg","url":"http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02788/eden-hazard_2788463b.jpg","visibleUrl":"www.telegraph.co.uk","title":"Chelsea manager Jose Mourinho purrs at \u003cb\u003eEden Hazard\u003c/b\u003e progress \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e","titleNoFormatting":"Chelsea manager Jose Mourinho purrs at Eden Hazard progress ...","originalContextUrl":"http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/chelsea/10566887/Chelsea-manager-Jose-Mourinho-purrs-at-Eden-Hazard-progress-following-defeat-of-Hull-City-at-KC-Stadium.html","content":"\u003cb\u003eEden\u003c/b\u003e project: \u003cb\u003eEden Hazard\u003c/b\u003e","contentNoFormatting":"Eden project: Eden Hazard","tbUrl":"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcTFohFJ8qoz1khvOSGcs2ECNfM_07JslDbVwEFP9t2GCAaZa8pNc6DwE_Y"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"424","height":"594","imageId":"ANd9GcQxgNBlBEWTh0cW37JQFyybSEnKDxqRbRpPDBaIN0H5e0i670UlKIPl6LtK","tbWidth":"96","tbHeight":"135","unescapedUrl":"http://statsbomb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Eden-Hazard-1.jpg","url":"http://statsbomb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Eden-Hazard-1.jpg","visibleUrl":"statsbomb.com","title":"Gifolution: Five Years of Belgian Wizard \u003cb\u003eEden Hazard\u003c/b\u003e | StatsBomb","titleNoFormatting":"Gifolution: Five Years of Belgian Wizard Eden Hazard | StatsBomb","originalContextUrl":"http://statsbomb.com/2014/06/gifolution-five-years-of-belgian-wizard-eden-hazard/","content":"Belgian Wizard \u003cb\u003eEden Hazard\u003c/b\u003e","contentNoFormatting":"Belgian Wizard Eden Hazard","tbUrl":"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQxgNBlBEWTh0cW37JQFyybSEnKDxqRbRpPDBaIN0H5e0i670UlKIPl6LtK"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"3600","height":"2502","imageId":"ANd9GcQ7yRG_Ba5H13m8EO0SbVI0APJ3saPSpv29Te_kYHNdjKxKk4NK_CdRnNOl","tbWidth":"150","tbHeight":"104","unescapedUrl":"https://nbcprosoccertalk.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/eden-hazard.jpeg","url":"https://nbcprosoccertalk.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/eden-hazard.jpeg","visibleUrl":"prosoccertalk.nbcsports.com","title":"\u003cb\u003eeden\u003c/b\u003e-\u003cb\u003ehazard\u003c/b\u003e.jpeg","titleNoFormatting":"eden-hazard.jpeg","originalContextUrl":"http://prosoccertalk.nbcsports.com/2014/03/05/eden-hazard-disputes-jose-mourinhos-claim-that-he-needs-rest/","content":"\u003cb\u003eeden\u003c/b\u003e-\u003cb\u003ehazard\u003c/b\u003e.jpeg","contentNoFormatting":"eden-hazard.jpeg","tbUrl":"http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQ7yRG_Ba5H13m8EO0SbVI0APJ3saPSpv29Te_kYHNdjKxKk4NK_CdRnNOl"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"1416","height":"1963","imageId":"ANd9GcT_8mqEplfLMNFSLC72uF7WjyIFkLDKCi4yz8hAtdMwS2A22ULs1yFnAoo","tbWidth":"108","tbHeight":"150","unescapedUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Eden_Hazard'13-14.JPG","url":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Eden_Hazard%2713-14.JPG","visibleUrl":"en.wikipedia.org","title":"\u003cb\u003eEden\u003c/b\u003e_\u003cb\u003eHazard\u003c/b\u003e\u0026#39;13-14.JPG","titleNoFormatting":"Eden_Hazard\u0026#39;13-14.JPG","originalContextUrl":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eden_Hazard","content":"\u003cb\u003eHazard\u003c/b\u003e playing against","contentNoFormatting":"Hazard playing against","tbUrl":"http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcT_8mqEplfLMNFSLC72uF7WjyIFkLDKCi4yz8hAtdMwS2A22ULs1yFnAoo"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GimageSearch","width":"490","height":"348","imageId":"ANd9GcSgXIPdlU7XG6KYvq6-YHpCf_Bl6F2ugD5Vzoi9zYO095uZmXQsSbTXAZ8","tbWidth":"130","tbHeight":"92","unescapedUrl":"http://www.ronaldo7.net/news/2014/01/775-eden-hazard-playing-for-chelsea-in-premier-league.jpg","url":"http://www.ronaldo7.net/news/2014/01/775-eden-hazard-playing-for-chelsea-in-premier-league.jpg","visibleUrl
```

01-23 13:57:43.283  32249-32249/com.paveynganpi.allsearch D/ImageGrid﹕ 0

Comment: Can you post the json you receive?

Comment: @vinitius hi, i just did, thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine. Maybe, `Picasso` is not recognizing your url as an `uri, because `load()` can also take a `String` path. Try `Uri.parse(mPicUrls.get(position))`. See if that works

Comment: i just realise, my mSmallImagesUrl variable is always out of scope, i dont know why, when i call getCurrentDetails, it shows i have 8 item in mSmallImagesUrl, but before i add it to me adapter, it has size 0. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry I let this pass. You're doing a async request. You have to set your adapter when you receive the response. The way it is now, you're passing to your adapter simply `new ArrayList<String>()` because your request didn't finish yet

Comment: oh ok thanks, pls do u know of any way to check if i have received a response, because in my okhhp enqueue method, there is an Onresponse() method, idont know if that is what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move:

```
 mGridView =(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesGrid);//reference to gridview
 ImagesGridAdapter adapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(getActivity(),mSmalImagesUrls);
 mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Response response) throws   IOException {

                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    } else {
                        mSmalImagesUrls = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        //Move it here
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                             public void run(){
                               mGridView =(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesGrid);//reference to gridview
                              ImagesGridAdapter adapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(getActivity(),mSmalImagesUrls);
                              mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                          }
                          });


...
```

Because you're doing an async request. Consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) later.

Comment: doing that i received this error ,android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  at com.paveynganpi.allsearch.ImageGrid$PlaceholderFragment$1.onResponse(ImageGrid.java:162).   the line at 162 is                                  mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Edited the answer , sorry

Comment: hey @vinius , the google image search url looks like this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=eden%20hazard&rsz=8&start=4 where the rsz parameter in the max images per page and the start parameter is the page number. I am able to get all imaged in a page. But have no idea to do that for say 20 pages, that is start= 0 ... 19. My code above shows how i did get the imaged from a page. Please let me know how i can make it get images for several pages. I tried using a for loop outside of me async task(okhttp enqueue) Thanks

Comment: Hey man, I suggest you open another question to clarify what exactly you want :D

Comment: thanks man, i did here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127078/getting-json-data-from-google-image-search-api-with-different-start-numbers