# getting json data from google image search api with different start numbers

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, okhttp, google-image-search

the google image search url looks like this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=eden%20hazard&rsz=8&start=4   where the rsz parameter in the max images per page and the start parameter is the page number. I am able to get all imaged in a page. But have no idea to do that for say 20 pages, that is start= 0 ... 19. My code below shows how i did get the imaged from a page. Please let me know how i can make it get images for several pages. I tried using a for loop outside of me async task(okhttp enqueue).

```
 package com.paveynganpi.allsearch;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.widget.AbsListView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import org.w3c.dom.Text;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class ImageGrid extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = ImageGrid.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_grid);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_image_grid, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    protected GridView mGridView;//reference to gridview in fragment_image_grid.xml
    protected int start = 0;//variable to change pages from google Api

    //contains extra images urls to supply to ... when need
    protected ArrayList<String> mBigImagesUrls;
    //contains image urls to inject into gridview
    protected  static ArrayList<String> mSmalImagesUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected static String mEditedString;


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_grid, container, false);

        final ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //gets the edited string from MainActivity
        Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        mEditedString = args.getString("space");

        String imagesUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="
                + mEditedString +"&rsz=8&start=" + start;


        //populate(start,imagesUrl.substring(0,imagesUrl.length()-1));

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

            //using okHttp library to connect to imagesUrl and retrieve JSON Data
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(imagesUrl).
                            build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);

            //runs the below code asynchronously
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "error from request");

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        //Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        } else {

                            mSmalImagesUrls = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    mGridView =(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesGrid);//reference to gridview
                                    ImagesGridAdapter adapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(getActivity(),mSmalImagesUrls);
                                    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                            });


                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught :", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    //get data
    private ArrayList<String> getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONObject responseData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");

        ArrayList<String> localList = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray results = responseData.getJSONArray("results");


        for(int i =0;i<results.length(); i++){

            localList.add(results.getJSONObject(i).getString("url"));

        }

        return localList;

    }


    //An AlertDialog to display to user when an error occurs
    private void alertUserAboutError() {

        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"error_dialog");


    }

    //checks if user is connected to a network
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;

        if(activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a method such as:

```
public String getImagesForPage(int page){
  return "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q="
            + mEditedString +"&rsz=8&start=" + page;

}
```

Then:

```
for (start=0;start<20;start++){

 if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

        //using okHttp library to connect to imagesUrl and retrieve JSON Data
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getImagesForPage(start)).
                        build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        //runs the below code asynchronously
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "error from request");

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                try {

                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    //Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    } else {

                        mSmalImagesUrls = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                mGridView =(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesGrid);//reference to gridview
                                ImagesGridAdapter adapter = new ImagesGridAdapter(getActivity(),mSmalImagesUrls);
                                mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        });


                    }
 ...
}
```

I recommend you create a method just with your connection logic. This code will download the 20 pages of contents and update your gridView everytime a request finishes. So, in the end of it, you'll have your gridView with the last page content. To just store the content of the pages, create a `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>` to store the urls for each page.

Comment: right, but wont the above give an error, like maybe the for loop will keep running ,increasing the values of start, while there is code running in the background for some previous start value. please let me know if what i am saying is right. thanks

Comment: For each new `thread` there is gonna be a new `callback()`. In this case, you don't have to worry about increasing values, because you're increasing the values in the main thread (`for`loop). If you need to change values inside your `Thread`, then you're going to need [Synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)